# Post matching query does not exist

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

urls.py

```
path('posts/',views.posts,name='posts'),

path('<id>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'mains/post.html', context)
```

post.html

```
{% block content %}

{% for topic in posts %}


    <a>{{ topic.description}}</a> <a href="{% url 'mains:detail_view' 
topic.post_owner.id %}">Show 
More</a><br>
    <br>

{% empty %}
  No yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Post matching query does not exist. This error is raising when i click on show_more in posts page. Please Help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this

```html
<a href="{% url 'mains:detail_view' topic.id %}">
```

instead of

```html
<a href="{% url 'mains:detail_view' topic.post_owner.id %}">
```

Because you're passing pk in views.py but not in your templates

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the hyperlink with ***post owner's PK***, but, your view expecting the Post's PK.

So, update the hyperlink logic in the template as,

```
<a href="{% url 'mains:detail_view' topic.post_owner.id %}">
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'mains:detail_view' id=topic.id %}">
```

Comment: Hello SIR, New error is raised named Reverse for 'detail_view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[^/]+)$']. Please help sir

Comment: @Progam Updated the answer. I hope now it should work